# Openlayers simple custom control example

Tags: openlayers

On the official openlayers site there is a [custom control example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/custom-controls.html) which demonstration a **class base** control.

Can anyone give an example of a simple custom control without class usage?

According to the [ol.control.Control](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.control.Control.html) specification, it should be possible to create one using the following statement

```
var myControl = new ol.control.Control({element: myElement});
```

but I'm quite new to javascript and cannot figure out yet how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Preparation for the custom control:

    var anchor_element = document.createElement('a');
    anchor_element.href = '#custom_href';
    anchor_element.className = 'custom_anchor';

    var this_ = this;
    var handleCustomControl = function (e) {
        myControl.customFunction(e);
    };

    anchor_element.addEventListener('click', handleCustomControl, false);
    anchor_element.addEventListener('touchstart', handleCustomControl, false);

    var custom_element = document.createElement('div');
    custom_element.className = 'myCustomControl ol-unselectable';
    custom_element.appendChild(anchor_element);

    myControl = new ol.control.Control({
        className: 'myControl',
        element: custom_element,
        target: document.getElementById("myCustomControl")


    });
```

CSS-rule (to be able to click on the hyperlink):

```
.custom_anchor:before {
    content:"Cycle";
}
```

I gave it a quick try and can use a custom Control:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/onn6g33c/

Probably it's a better choice to set up a control like this if it's getting a bit more complex:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/j4duqc9s/

Comment: I'm trying to make that example from openlayers site as simple as possible and following your example have got the following. https://jsfiddle.net/yaugenka/62y73Ls8/3/
Can you check what is missing there?

Comment: the value to rotate is zero, not the letter 'o' and it's ol.control.Control and not ol.Control.Control: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/62y73Ls8/6/  ;)

Comment: Now it works! Thank you @TomasB. I'll add an extra answer with this code.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simplified version of that custom control example.

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'N';

var handleRotateNorth = function(e) {
    map.getView().setRotation(0);
};

button.addEventListener('click', handleRotateNorth, false);

var element = document.createElement('div');
element.className = 'rotate-north ol-unselectable ol-control';
element.appendChild(button);

var RotateNorthControl = new ol.control.Control({
    element: element
});
map.addControl(RotateNorthControl);
```

You can see complete code at http://jsfiddle.net/yaugenka/62y73Ls8/7/