# How can I contribute to openlayers examples list?

Tags: openlayers

Who or where to can I post a request to add an example to the [openlayers 3 examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/) list?

Particularly I would like to ask to add [this simple custom control example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165009/59562) because it is quite hard for new users to understand custom control class usage in the [custom control example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/custom-controls.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OpenLayers actively encourages forking and contributing to their Github repository I'd say this is the best starting point.

The examples can be found on [ol3/examples](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/tree/master/examples) - so you should be able to fork it, include your example and create a pull request.