# Creating new buttons and removing default ones - Openlayers-3

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to create new buttons but I seem to use the wrong function.
To delete the default buttons I added the following code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: [],
  layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({ ... etc
```

This works great.
Now I am trying to connect a button I created with HTML (id=btnZoomOut) to the Zoom function:

```
var buttonZoomOut = new ol.control.Control({element: $('#btnZoomOut')});
map.addControl(new ol.control.Zoom({target: buttonZoomOut}));
```

But this does not seems to works and trows an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).appendChild is not a function
```

How to correctly do this?

Comment: Will this `#btnZoomOut` element be outside of map? If you just want to change zoom control position you can pass a custom CSS class to the constructor.

Comment: No, I want to change the entire look and add more buttons for locking to views. But if I can't even create one new button...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change zoom buttons:

```
map.addControl(new ol.control.Zoom({
    className: 'custom-zoom'
}));
```

CSS, this is up to you:

```
.custom-zoom{
    bottom: .5em;
    left: .5em;
}
.custom-zoom button{
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, .7);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

To create new controls:
[Openlayers simple custom control example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/164629/50718)

Comment: I was waiting for you ^^ Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: :) at your service.

Comment: Is there a possibility to connect a function like zooming to an existing button?

Comment: Yes, you set an element on `target` constructor property, or use http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.control.Zoom.html#setTarget. Don't forget to accept my answer (if it is correct) so it won't remain incomplete.

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept! Thanks for the additional info,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use font awesome icons then

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';

var handleRotateNorth = function(e) {
    map.getView().setRotation(0);
};

button.addEventListener('click', handleRotateNorth, false);

var element = document.createElement('div');
element.className = 'rotate-north ol-unselectable ol-control';
element.appendChild(button);

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
    rotation: 0
  }),
  controls:ol.control.defaults().extend([
          new ol.control.Control({
            element:element
          })
        ])
});
```

[jsfiddle working code](http://jsfiddle.net/jophine/6Lef091s/)