# How to specify custom CSS to an OpenLayers Zoom Control in Angular 6?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I am attempting to modify the Zoom buttons on **OpenLayers 5.3** in an **Angular 6** component. And I'm using this **OL3** question as a starting point: [Creating new buttons and removing default ones - Openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165342/creating-new-buttons-and-removing-default-ones-openlayers-3).

However, my custom CSS class for my component is being ignored (or overwritten with the original ol.css for the zoom buttons).

```
this.map = new OlMap({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new OlTileLayer({
      source: new OlOSM()
    })
  ],
  view: this.view,
  controls: [
    new OlZoom({ className: 'custom-zoom' })
  ]
```

And I've placed `.custom-zoom` and `.custom-zoom button` in my scss for my component, but they do not render for the Zoom buttons.

Any ideas on an **Angular 6** solution to custom CSS classes for the Zoom buttons?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Angular a style in `@Component` will only be applied to its own template (see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope) You basically have two options:

1. Overwrite the style in your global `style.scss`.

   ```
   .ol-control button {
       background-color: red;
   }
   ```
2. ([deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)) Use ::ng-deep in your component style.

   ```
   ::ng-deep .ol-control button {
       background-color: red;
   }
   ```

For more information on the whole `/deep/` deprecation see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep) for example.

Answer (score 0):

[This should be a comment] You could overwrite the styles of ol.css with your custom ones. Just take their file (https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/ol.css) 
copy the ones you need to your scss file, customize it, and then import it after ol.css.

Comment: This will not work. Angular encapsulates styles in its components. So when one declares a component local style it will not be applied to markup outside of its own template.